# Is there a way to calculate integrals directly, rather than through an approximation like sums in Riemann integral?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, functional-analysis, analysis

Is there a way to calculate integrals directly, rather than through an approximation like sums in Riemann integral?

By "directly" I mean to produce the integral *as it is* ("analytically") w/o resorting to a method that approximates it through simpler shapes. So e.g. perhaps such method would somehow infer, what an area, volume etc. must be, given what size the boundary has?

I thought that shouldn't Fourier analysis lend itself to the discovery of such method, but maybe not?

Comment: Does $\int_a^b f(x) \, dx = F(b) - F(a)$ count?

Comment: If there were such a method, it would be the most fundamental theorem of calculus

Comment: @HansLundmark Yes, but is it always usable?

Comment: To find the size of a boundary you also need to integrate.

Answer (score 0):

The OP asked for a way to interpret integration analytically but without approximating with simpler shapes.

Unfortunately, approximating the integral with Riemann (or Lebesgue) sum is **the** analytic definition of integral.

The OP also asked whether an integral can be calculated from the length of the curve of the boundary.

The length of the boundary of a curve generally does not depend on its area. Also, the length of the graphic of a function is expressed as an integral $\int_a^b\sqrt{1+f(x)^2}dx$. So, to find the length of a curve you have to find another integral, which is often more complicated.

That said, I assume the OP meant interpreting integration **algebraically**, rather than analytically, because in that case the question makes sense.

If we interpret integration as an algebraic operation, inverse to [formal differentiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_derivative), we do not use the analytic, Riemann sum definition of an integral, we just apply formal rules of integration.

For instance, in [formal power series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_power_series) there is no sense to talk about the area under the curve.

In that case, integration can be represented as multiplying the power series with this infinite matrix:

$$D^{-1}=\left(
\begin{array}{cccccc}
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & . \\
 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & . \\
 0 & \frac{1}{2} & 0 & 0 & 0 & . \\
 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{3} & 0 & 0 & . \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{4} & 0 & . \\
 . & . & . & . & . & . \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

Comment: But one has to discover what power series describes the object one has?